# How to browse my local website running on Mac OS X from my guest VMWare Windows 7 machine?

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion

I am running OS X Mountain Lion as the host, and Windows 7 inside a VMWare Fusion 4.1.3 machine. I have a local website running on the host (under port 5000).

I want to access this website from the guest. My host IP address is 192.168.45.2, and my guest IP address is 192.168.130.25.

From the guest - inside Command Line - I can ping my host using 192.168.45.2. However, when I go to Internet Explorer, and go to

```
http://192.168.45.2:5000
```

I get a 404 error.

Under the Network Adaptor for VMWare Fusion - I have the Network Adaptor enabled and am sharing the Mac's Network Connection (NAT).

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Joerg: You're getting downvoted/voted to close because this question is offtopic for StackOverflow (SO is for programming questions).  However, it's being marked as more suitable for SuperUser, which is a similar site that's more likely to give you a correct answer.  I've posted a suggestion below that may help - but the whole thread will likely be migrated to SuperUser shortly!

Comment: Downvoters: this question is offtopic, but it's not a bad question: details are good and it shows some level of effort.  I'd agree with closing/migrating the question, but I don't think it deserves downvotes.

Comment: Ok cool - sorry. Should I wait for it to be migrated first?

Comment: I don't think it matters (and it may not happen - it has to be voted offtopic by five people before it'll migrate).  If my answer works then go for it :-)

Answer (score 0):

The website should be accessible on your host NAT adapter address (vmnet8).

```
http://192.168.130.1:5000
```

Be sure your web server is listening on the NAT interface or all interfaces.

```
netstat -an|grep LISTEN
```

Comment: If they're seeing a 404 error, the server *is* accessible.

Comment: @Dan Puzey. You're right, I was focalized on the Bridged/NAT aspect of the question and missed the 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

A 404 error is the server telling you that the page you've requested does not exist; if you're getting a 404 error then that indicates that you *are* getting to the server.

I'd suggest you either add a valid page name to the url (e.g. `http://192.168.45.2:5000/index.html`) or make sure there's a default document set on the website.  But the important point is: this is *not* a networking error.

Comment: (I had tried that as well - but to no avail). I could even put in a random IP address into Internet Explorer - and it kept on giving me a 404 error. I looked through the various options inside IE - and found that it was connecting via a proxy - which I removed, and now it works!